# next.js rate limit for image loading

Tags: javascript, next.js, rate-limiting

In my Next.js project, I'm facing an issue where a single user is downloading a public image multiple times from my project by rapidly refreshing the page. This can consume up to 30GB of data transfer in a single day, which incurs additional costs for me.

I have a request rate limiter set up for the API and pages, but I have no idea how to apply it to a link to a static image, which url can easily be copied.